# Hp elitebook 840 G3 Keyboard backlight not detected

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, hp, brightness, backlight

I'm having issues with an [HP elitebook 840 G3](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05259054). I cannot access information regarding the keyboard back light on Ubuntu 18.04

My keyboard back light works normally (with pressing Fn and F3), that's not the issue, issue is being not able to read back light level from software.

I looked at `/sys/class/leds/` and there was nothing that could be keyboard backlight, there were only:

```
_hp::hddprotect_
_input3::capslock_
_input3::numlock_
_input3::scrolllock_
_phy0-led_
```

Can anyone help me understand where that device might be located so I could read data about it? In order to be sure the keyboard has back light and view/control its brightness level?

Answer (score 0):

**Turn the backlight on or off**

If your notebook computer has a backlit keyboard, press the <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd> (depending on your model) key on the keyboard to turn the light on or off. It might be necessary to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> (function) key at the same time.

Look carefully on the keys· if a backlight icon is not on the <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd> key, then look for the backlit-key on the row of function keys.

Good luck!

Source: https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c01612362